# Firebase rules - Cannot access to each node

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm working on an app using Firebase. I have the following data structure on Firebase:

```
{
   rules: {
      "version": {
         "threads": {
            "$thread": {
               "noticeList": {
                   ".read": true,
                   ".write": true
               },
               "messages": {
                   ".read": "root.child('version/threads/' + $thread + '/users/' + auth.uid).exists()",
                   ".write": "root.child('version/threads/' + $thread + '/users/' + auth.uid).exists()"
               },
               "$other": {
                    ".read": "auth != null",
                    ".write": "auth != null"
               }
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Each thread has subnode `/users/` and I want to make a rule that only included users can read and write the messages in that thread.

There are one more condition that I have to access to `noticeList` when the new messages are added. However, these rules do not work. If there are other node rules in the '$thread', I couldn't get any respond when I used

```
firebase.child("version/threads/" + $thread + "/noticeList").once("value", function(snapshot) {});
```

or

```
firebase.child("version/threads").once("value", function(snapshot) {});
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query starts at this:

```
firebase.child("version/threads/" + $thread + "/noticeList")
```

When you execute this query, Firebase checks if the user has rights to read the node. Which in this case the user doesn't, so the query fails.

This is a common mistake people make when it comes to Firebase security rules. The Firebase documentation explains it as "[rules are not filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter)", which is exactly what you're trying to do.

Unfortunately for your scenario, the documentation also explains that "[rules cascade](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade)". This essentially means that if you give users read access to `noticeList`, you cannot take te read access away at a lower level.

The easiest way to get this to work is probably to give each user their own index of notices they can access.

```
version
  threads
    $thread
      userNoticeList
        <userid1>
          <messageid1>: true
          <messageid2>: true
        <userid2>
          <messageid1>: true
          <messageid3>: true
```

This is a fairly typical denormalization of the data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We decide to change some logics and structure in our app through your comments.

Comment: do I understand it right that I have to always have a parent node <uid> if I want to give only the owner user access to the data?