# Firebase rules for anonymous authentication

Tags: authentication, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire, anonymous

I am using anonymous authentication with my app in which when the user opens the app he/she will be authenticated and the session will not end once the app closes.

I am having trouble figuring out how to code the read write rules. What I would like is for the user to be able to read and write their own entries without seeing any other users.

I have managed to authenticate the user as shown in the console logs below.

Firebase Structure:

```
"rounds" : {
    "-KBNYNvCAb-Wywq6yowW" : {
      "Arrow1" : "1",
      "Arrow2" : "1",
      "Arrow3" : "2",
      "Arrow4" : "2",
      "Arrow5" : "1",
      "Arrow6" : "1",
      "Bow" : "Hoyt",
      "Date" : 1456405827389,
      "Distance" : "10m",
      "RoundName" : "Dcedc",
      "Season" : "Indoor",
      "TotalScore" : 8,
      "UID" : "9ddc8eb2-6f1a-4c26-bac3-b5b473104bb6"
```

the current code in the read write is:

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "rounds": {
      "$rounds":{
        ".read": "auth.uid === data.child('UID').val()",
          ".write": "auth.uid === data.child('UID').val()"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This only works in the simulator when I add the randomly generated table name in the url, for example

```
rounds/-KBNYNvCAb-Wywq6yowW
```

The controller to get the uid is in my controller here:

```
      app.controller('scoreCtrl', function($scope, roundInfo, equipmentStore){
      ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
            if (authData) {
      $scope.rounds = roundInfo;
      $scope.bow = roundInfo;
      $scope.round = roundInfo;
      $scope.date = new Date();
      $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.round.$add({
            "RoundName": roundInfo.name,
            "Distance": roundInfo.distance,
            "Season": roundInfo.season,
            "Date": this.date? this.date.getTime() : null,
            "Bow": $scope.bow.title.title,
            "Arrow1": roundInfo.arrow1,
            "Arrow2": roundInfo.arrow2,
            "Arrow3": roundInfo.arrow3,
            "Arrow4": roundInfo.arrow4,
            "Arrow5": roundInfo.arrow5,
            "Arrow6": roundInfo.arrow6,
            "TotalScore" : +roundInfo.arrow1 + +roundInfo.arrow2 + +roundInfo.arrow3 + +roundInfo.arrow4 + +roundInfo.arrow5 + +roundInfo.arrow6,
            "UID": authData.uid
                    });
                };
            }
      });
  });
```

Round Factory:

```
    app.factory('roundInfo', function($rootScope, $firebaseArray) {
    var roundRef = new Firebase("https://firebaseLink.firebaseio.com/rounds");
        roundInfo = {};
        roundInfo.name = '';
        roundInfo.bow = '';  
        roundInfo.date = '';
        roundInfo.distance = '';
        roundInfo.season = '';
        roundInfo.arrow1 = '';

            return $firebaseArray(roundRef);
```

});

The firebase authentication controllers:

```
        var ref = new Firebase("https://firebaseLink.firebaseio.com");
ref.authAnonymously(function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
  }
  if (authData) {
    console.log("user logged in")
  } else {
    console.log("user logged out:")
  }    
});



    var ref = new Firebase("https://firebaseLink.firebaseio.com");
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log("Authenticated with uid:", authData.uid);
  } else {
    console.log("Client unauthenticated.")
  }
});
```

The console logs confirm that the user has been authenticated:

```
0     450893   log      Client unauthenticated.
1     451712   log      Authenticated with uid:, 9ee68f25-d6ba-4902-9d83-329d0acf996e
2     451713   log      Authenticated successfully with payload:, [object Object
```

Comment: Also posted: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/9VRyKIepMPs and https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/47qhu1/question_firebase_rules_help/

Comment: Your updates make it clear: you're trying to query from `rounds`, but nobody has read permission on `rounds`. My answer explains why that is, but it's a duplicate of the ones I link to there. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249956/firebase-rules-cannot-access-to-each-node

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing some crucial information (such as what operation is failing), but I'm going to take an educated guess here.

You're most likely trying to read from `rounds` and aiming to get back only the children that the user has access to. Something like:

```
ref.child('rounds').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  ...
})
```

This is not how Firebase security rules work.

**To be able to read or query a location, you must have read permission at that location.**

The trap you've fallen for is covered under the section [rules are not filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter) in the Firebase documentation.

So in your rules, since the user doesn't have read permission on `rounds` the read operation will fail. This is one of the reasons why it's often better to store the items under the user that owns them:

```
user_rounds
  "9ddc8eb2-6f1a-4c26-bac3-b5b473104bb6"
    "-KBNYNvCAb-Wywq6yowW": true
    ...
```

Some questions dealing with the exact same problem:

- [How to use Firebase rules to only give permission to certain leaf nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038981/how-to-use-firebase-rules-to-only-give-permission-to-certain-leaf-nodes)
- [firebase rules not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139215/firebase-rules-not-working)
- [Restricting child/field access with security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296625/restricting-child-field-access-with-security-rules)
- [Firebase rules - Cannot access to each node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249956/firebase-rules-cannot-access-to-each-node)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding read/write rules to the parent "rounds"

```
"rules" {
"rounds" {
      ".read":"true",
      ".write":"true", 
   "$ rounds": {....}}}
```